# PHP login "invalid username and password"

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a simple php login system. And even if the username & password exists in the database, it doesn't work but shows "invalid username & password" error message.

```
<?php
session_start();

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysqli_select_db($con,"server2go");

    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
        echo "<h2>Failed to connect to MySQL database!".mysqli_connect_errno();

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {   
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POSt['password'];   

        $sql=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username FROM userlogin WHERE username='$username' AND     password='$password' limit 1 ");

        if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)==1)
        {                           
            $data=mysqli_fetch_array($sql,1);
            $_SESSION['username']=$data['username'];
            header("location:dashboard.php");               
        }
        else             
            $error="Invalid username or password!";         
    }
?>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you storing passwords in cleartext ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$password=$_POSt['password'];
```

to

```
$password=$_POST['password'];
```

Comment: thnks...by the way :)

Comment: Honestly dunno why i found this so funny hahah